# How to clear /dev/dm-0

Tags: filesystems, fstab, dev

I noticed /dev/dm-0 is using almost all my HDD space:

```
$ df -h
[...]
/dev/dm-0          227G    207G  8,8G  96% /
[...]
```

I believe /dev/dm-0 is some kind of cache for mounted filesystem (It is the only explanation of the space it takes). I used to have cifs and davfs filesystems mounted (not anymore).

```
$ sudo dmsetup info /dev/dm-0
Name:              xubuntu--vg-root
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        256
Tables present:    LIVE
Open count:        1
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      252, 0
Number of targets: 1
UUID: LVM-bfWJM099v9DmeZewLVs0jpHMLszZkEASvQAZQLM0YUheaQnmXjBcT1K0Epxjsrp7
```

Do you know how I can clear /dev/dm-0?

Comment: I have the same issue. I did not create an LVM.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a cache, it's the *actual* filesystem. Instead of fixed-size partitions, your system uses LVM which allows for "easier" resizing of volumes. Run `lsblk` to see how everything is stacked, or `vgs` and `lgs` to see the LVM volumes.